# NodeJS cluster global variable

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I'm trying to execute a function in a specific cluster, but I'm having some strange issues with assigning variables in my master process.

```
const cluster   = require('cluster');

let _checkId = null; // This stores the cluster id

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // Assign _checkId
        if(_checkId === null) _checkId = (i + 1);

        console.log(_checkId);

        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    console.log('Cluster id: ' + cluster.worker.id);
    console.log('_checkId ' + _checkId);
    console.log(_checkId === cluster.worker.id);
}
```

The output for this is:

```
1
1
1
Cluster id: 3
_checkId null // --> This doesn't make sense
false
Cluster id: 1
_checkId null
false
Cluster id: 2
_checkId null
false
```

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is that I can have multiple clusters, but only one cluster should execute a specific function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you're specifying to do: _checkId does equal null, and only is assigned on your master process

```
const cluster   = require('cluster');

let _checkId = null; // This stores the cluster id

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // Assign _checkId
        if(_checkId === null) _checkId = (i + 1);

        console.log(_checkId);

        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    // _checkId remains null
    _checkId = 'foo';
    console.log('Cluster id: ' + cluster.worker.id);
    console.log('_checkId ' + _checkId);
    console.log(_checkId === cluster.worker.id);
}
```

This yields

```
Cluster id: 3
_checkId foo // --> This makes sense
...
Cluster id: 1
_checkId foo
...
Cluster id: 2
_checkId foo
...
```

Comment: I'm not really following, the `cluster.fork()` only happens after I assigned `_checkId`, therefore it should only get in the `else` statement after it's assigned. Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: And in that case, given the following code: http://pastebin.com/D1tGikWt, why would the output still be: `3, _checkId: 3, 2, _checkId: 2, 1, _checkId: 1`

Comment: it doesn't work that way, perhaps you can deduce what's happening: the app itself is not on the main cluster, and the scope of each process is more or less independent, hence, the notoriously sucky interprocess comm issues where others are more suitable.

Comment: Aha, I understand now. Makes sense now that I think about it.